# I am trying to delete the records in excel from column 1 to 35

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

// Here I am trying to delete all the rows starting from column 1
 to 35.But while deleting the records, some records are left behind and
 its not deleting all the rows. I am unable to understand where the
 problem actually is.Is it the problem with the task manager but already I am killing the exe files. I am looping through all the rows from second row till the last row and hence if the records are not empty,I am deleting the records with the help of get_range one by one.

```
public static void GetIncidentExcel(string Incident_Path, List<excelObj> ListTickets)
{

    lastRow = 0;
    MyApp = new Excel.Application();
    //  MyApp.Visible = false;
    MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(Incident_Path);
    MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets["BOXI_summary"]; // Explict cast is not required here
    lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;

    for (int i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++)
    {
        Array MyValues = (Array)MySheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "AI" + i.ToString()).Cells.Value;

        if (Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 1)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 2)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 3)) == "" &&
            Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 4)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 5)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 6)) == "" &&
            Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 7)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 8)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 9)) == "" &&
            Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 10)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 11)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 12)) == "" &&
            Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 13)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 14)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 15)) == "" &&
            Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 16)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 17)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 18)) == "" &&
            Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 19)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 20)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 21)) == "" &&
            Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 22)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 23)) == "")
            break;
        else
        {
            Excel.Range cells = MySheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "AI" + i.ToString());
            cells.Delete();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try running the loop backwards.

Comment: I have tried looping backwards, its not working.Aain some records are undeleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your loop with something like this:

```
for (int i = lastRow; i >= 2; i--)
{
    if (MyApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "AI" + i.ToString())) == 0)
    {
        MySheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "AI" + i.ToString()).Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
    }
}
```

You can use the `WorksheetFunction` object to check if all the cells are empty, and when deleting rows you should **always** loop backwards

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. But again rows are undeleted.

Comment: When you say "Rows" do you actually want the _entire_ row to be deleted? or just the cells in column A:AI? Are you getting any exceptions when you try to delete them?

Comment: yes not the entire row, but all rows with column 1 to 35.

Comment: and not getting any exception while deleting.

Comment: are _any_ rows getting deleted?

Comment: with the earlier code which i have written above, half of the rows are getting deleted and half are left behind.

Comment: In which case it would appear you have some non-displaying characters in your cells, try stepping through the code and checking what the boolean comparisons evaluate to when you're testing for blanks

Comment: At a time 40-50 records are getting deleted and like that after many executions ,its deleting all the records.